# Cache a guild user by id discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a moderation bot with my friend and I am trying to make it so if a user is muted when the bot restarts or crashes, on startup it loops all users in my database per guild and checks if they still have mute time to serve, then use a `setTimeout()` to wait however long until their `muted` role gets removed, however the bot does not have the user cached so I get an error where the user is undefined. If anyone knows how to cache a user by id or do this in another way any help is appreciated.

**My code:**

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setActivity(process.env.STATUS);
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    console.log(`Guilds: ${client.guilds.cache.size}`);
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(function (guild) {
        console.log(guild.name, ":", guild.id);
        for (user in db.get(`${guild.id}.users`)) {
            if (
                ms(db.get(`${guild.id}.users.${moderation.mute.time}`)) +
                    Date.now(db.get(`${guild.id}.users.${moderation.mute.date}`)) >=
                Date.now()
            ) {
                let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
                    (mR) => mR.name === "Muted"
                );
                if (!mutedRole)
                    mutedRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
                        data: { name: "Muted", color: "#000000", permissions: [] },
                    });
                client.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel) => {
                    await channel.updateOverwrite(mutedRole, {
                        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                        SPEAK: false,
                        VIDEO: false,
                        ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                        SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
                        ATTACH_FILES: false,
                    });
                });
                let user = client.users.cache.get(user);
                user.roles.remove(mutedRole);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you use `message` in ready state, ready state don't has message object. 
Bad way try find role by name, bad way use `client.users.fetch()` for get a user, because it's a chached collection. And you use await on channel.updateOverwrite, so if it will rejected you code will stop. You need use `try catch` or `.then and .catch`

Answer (score 0):

You can cache or even save the `id` of a user and get the assigned `GuildMember` back by this method:

```
// 'user' will become the GuildMember of your cached id
let user = null;

// 'cachedId' is the id of the cached user
let cachedId = yourCachedId;

client.users.fetch(cachedId).then(usr => {user = usr})
```